# How to compile emacs 26.2 with gnutls on Centos 7?

Tags: emacs, compilation, gnutls

I try to compile Emacs 26.2 on Centos 7. So I run

```
./configure
```

But the script complains:

```
configure: error: The following required libraries were not found:
     gnutls
Maybe some development libraries/packages are missing?
```

However yum tells me that `gnutls` is already installed:

```
Package gnutls-3.3.29-9.el7_6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

What else do I miss to compile Emacs with gnutls support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try installing the package `gnutls-devel`.  While the `gnutls` package contains the files needed to *run* a program that uses GnuTLS, `gnutls-devel` is needed to *compile* a program using GnuTLS.

Comment: Makes sense! Will try it tomorrow!